How is a component with multiple setInterval() tested?
There are two setInterval() functions within a component I'm working on. Once the function start_new_game sets the component state variable level equal to '0', the component will invoke useEffect. The state setter within the effect, setActiveColor, sets a state variable which is used to conditionally set the css classes on a button.
When running the app with npm run dev, both functions with the setInterval calls are performing state changes as expected. As for running the test, it appears I can only get the timer for start_new_game to run when it's advanced to 2000ms. To initiate the timer in useEffect, I advanced it to 850ms in hopes that it would trigger the state changes there but the test still fails.
vi.advanceTimersByTime(850);
expect(
    await screen.findByRole("button", {name: "red_pad"})
).toHaveClass("highlight_red");

Error: expect(element).toHaveClass("highlight_red")

Expected the element to have class:
  highlight_red
Received:
  pad pad_red


    function start_new_game() {
        //When "start" is clicked the game display will
        //blink "--" until the game is ready to play
        let i = 0;
        const indicators =  [undefined, "- -", undefined, "0"];
        const interval_id = setInterval(
            () => {
                const indicator = indicators[i];
                setLevel(indicator);
                if (indicator === "0") {
                    clearInterval(interval_id);
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }, 500
        );
    }

        useEffect(
        () => {
                if (!isNaN(level)) {
                    let id = setInterval(() => {
                        setActiveColor('red');
                        clearInterval(id);
                    }, 850);

                }

        }, [level]
    );

test(
    `Verify that pads light up in the order presented in the current round sequence`, async () => {
        let user = userEvent.setup();
        render(<Simon />);
        await user.click(screen.getByRole("button", {name: "turn_game_on"}));
        expect(screen.getByText("- -")).toBeInTheDocument();
        await user.click(screen.getByRole("button", {name: "start_new_game"}));
        vi.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
        expect(await screen.findByText("0")).toBeVisible();
        const red_pad = screen.getByRole("button", {name: "red_pad"});
        vi.advanceTimersByTime(850);
        waitFor(() => expect(red_pad).toHaveClass("highlight_red"));
    }
);

